# Issue with loading multiple comma delaminated text in excel using VBA

Tags: vba, excel, csv

Good morning,

I am trying to load multiple comma delaminated  casv style file with .plt extension in excel with.

What I am trying to do is to load openfolder dialogue and select the folder where my codes are saved wit the first bit of code and paste the path in TextBox1. I have managed to successfully do that. 
Then I am trying to run further codes with the run button to load all files in a new workbook with filenames as sheet name. But I am struggling with the following 2 things:

1. When I try to open the file in new workbook, each file opening in new workbook but I want them to just open 1 new workbook with each files in different worksheets.
2. The program works fine when I manually assign directory path but when I ask the program to read the folder path where the files are saved from the textbox its failing

Could someone please give me some advise on how to rectify this, many thanks. My codes are as follows:

I have added comments on possibly where I think I am doing something wrong as by replacing the commented sections manually with the file path sich as "C:\Users\Desktop\test\" the program works fine to load in same workbook all files.

```
   'Code for the button on the right of textbox 1
    Private Sub FilePath_Button_Click()
    get_folder
    End Sub

    ' code for the run button
    Private Sub Run_Button_Click()
    load_file
    End Sub

    Private Sub TextBox1_Change()

    End Sub

    Private Sub UserForm_Click()

    End Sub

'code for the fild open dialouge box to locate folder where the files are saved 

    Public Sub get_folder()
      Dim FolderName As String
    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
      .AllowMultiSelect = False
      .Show
      On Error Resume Next
      FolderName = .SelectedItems(1)
      Err.Clear
      On Error GoTo 0
    End With
    TextBox1.Text = FolderName
    End Sub


    'codes for the run button to import the files
    Sub load_file()
    Dim strFile As String
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    strFile = Dir("TextBox1.Text*.plt") ' I think this is the bit where I doing something wrong
    Do While strFile <> vbNullString
    Set ws = Sheets.Add
    With ws.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
        "TEXT;" & "TextBox1.Text" & strFile, Destination:=Range("$A$1")) ' and also "TextBox1.Text" I think not right as if i replace this two section that I commented with the file path manually the program works fine
        .Name = strFile
        .FieldNames = True
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
        .TextFilePlatform = 437
        .TextFileStartRow = 1
        .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
        .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
        .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
        .TextFileTabDelimiter = False
        .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
        .TextFileCommaDelimiter = True
        .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
        .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
        .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
    strFile = Dir
    Loop
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing:

```
strFile = Dir("TextBox1.Text*.csv") ' I think this is the bit where I doing something wrong
    Do While strFile <> vbNullString
    Set ws = Sheets.Add
```

with

```
StrFile = Dir(Me.TextBox1.Text & "\*.csv")

Do While Len(StrFile) > 0
    Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Add
    ws.Name = StrFile
```

**EDIT**

To add the .csv files to new workbooks

```
Dim wb as workbook

    Do While Len(StrFile) > 0
        Set wb = Workbooks.Add
        'added workbook becomes the activeworkbook
        Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Add
        ws.Name = StrFile
```

Comment: Thanks a lot :) yes that worked great, could you please advice me on how can I load these files in a new workbook instead of the active workbook?

Comment: Just realised its not working if I specify the the following line as this:   With ws.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
    "TEXT;" & Me.TextBox1.Text & strFile, Destination:=Range("$A$1")) but when I replace the 'Me.TextBox1.Text' bit with  the full file path then it is working, could you advise me on this line too?

Comment: Ayan - I have edited the answer to 'add new Workbook' question. I can't say I'm familar with the use Query Tables but by observation you might remove the quotation marks around "TextBox1.Text" near the start of your 'With ws.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _' line.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion with the new workbook which I managed to adopt to my code with slight alterration. I am still having issue with the line With ws.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
    "TEXT;" & Me.TextBox1.Text  & strFile, Destination:=Range("$A$1")). Not sure why but I will try to look for  sollution in the previous examples, thanks a lot for your help

Comment: just to let you know I have managed to resolve the minor issue, basically it was just missing the '& "\" &' from the code and thats all! :) thanks a lot for you guidence to get to here

Answer (score 0):

Is there any reason you are using a QueryTable? Just opening the workbook and copying the sheet should suffice as the CSV file will already have the sheetname as the filename.

Try replacing the `load_file()` procedure with this:

```
Sub load_file()

Dim wb1 As Workbook, wb2 As Workbook
Dim filePath As String, strFile As String

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set wb1 = ActiveWorkbook

filePath = TextBox1.Text

strFile = Dir(filePath)
    While Not strFile = ""
        If LCase(Right(strFile, 4)) = ".plt" Then


Set wb2 = Workbooks.OpenText(Filepath:=fileName & "\" & strFile, Datatype:=xlDelimited, Comma:=True) '// open the workbook
        wb2.Sheets(1).Copy after:=wb1.Sheets(wb1.Sheets.Count) '// copy the page to wb1
        wb2.Close False '// close wb2
        Set wb2 = Nothing '// release from memory
    End If
    strFile = Dir()
Wend

Set wb1 = Nothing

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

MsgBox "Done"

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your post, the suggestion is not working for me when I try. it is not giving any errors and just giving a message box done but I do not get any new 'wb2' book open. I wonder if this is cause my extensions are csv style with '.plt'. they are comma seperated texts excatly like csv. I have changes the code to 'If LCase(Right(strFile, 4)) = ".plt" Then' but not loading anything with this code

Comment: edited code above to open as comma delimited text file. Can you try that and let me know?

Comment: Can you also rename the question to explain that you are opening a comma delimited text file and not a .csv file - you may get more responses.

Comment: thanks for your comments back I have just tried your code as this would be lot simpler then what I wrote but i get an error 'Compiled error: Named argument not found' when I call your procedure with the run button. not sure why? I have changed the questions and texts to highlight its comma delimited file that I am using, thanks again

Comment: Sorry, I had mis-spelt "xlDelimited" in my code above - I've amended with the correct spelling (d'oh!)

Hopefully should work now

Comment: I am still getting the same error for some reason, is anything wrong with the following line - Workbooks.OpenText(filePath:=filePath & "\" & strFile, DataType:=xlDelimited, Comma:=True)?

Comment: Sorry, yes "FilePath:=" should be "FileName:="

Really not on form today, and I'm writing it freehand as I have nothing to test on.